# How well does NHibernate handle large models (about 1000 tables)?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, scalability

I have seen a few discussions about how well Entity Framework works with large models - most prominently [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981054/entity-framework-4-handling-very-large-1000-tables-data-models).

But I haven't been able to find any substantial information about how well NHibernate handles large models - what are the difficulties, and are they not too hard to work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that many models, the session factory gets really expensive to build. The common workaround is to [cache the configuration to a file](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.html).

IIRC [ConfORM](https://bitbucket.org/fabiomaulo/conform) doesn't use XML/HBM config so it might be faster than NHibernate/XML or Fluent NHibernate in these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issues with large models.

Of course, for ease of maintenance, you should use a conventions-based data mapping approach, like [ConfORM](http://code.google.com/p/codeconform/) or [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/).